# Connecting multiple temperature and humidity sensors to the Pi 4

Tags: gpio

Every article I have read about connecting multiple temperature and humidity sensors to the Pi 4 use the same GPIO 4. Is it not possible to use another pin? I realise that each sensor has a serial number and the Pi will recognise them, but what if you have to replace a faulty sensor, do you have to re-program it?
To be more specific I would like to connect a DHT22 Temperature and Humidity probe, and two DS18B20 temperature probes to a Pi 4 do all the data wires from the sensors connect to GPIO4?

Comment: the title of your post is different from the actual question

Comment: Which sensors?  There are many types and they may use differing communications protocols, e.g. I2C, SPI, 1-wire bus, 1-wire protocol etc. etc.  They each have different constraints.

Comment: the default for `onewire` is GPIO 4, so I'm assuming you're referring to onewire protocol - in that case, no, you don't "reprogram" the sensor - since the serialnumber is burnt into ROM, i.e. can't be changed, - but, yes, you'd need to change your code if you have hardcoded serial number(s) in your code

Comment: I would like to connect a DHT22 Temperature and Humidity probe, and an additional 3 DS18B20 temperature probes to a Pi for a project. Does the data cable from the sensors have to be connected to GPIO 4 or can you use other IO pins?

Comment: Add clarifications to the question to the question, not in comments.  People respond to the given question, not the given question and comments.

Answer (score 1):

The DS18B20 uses the 1-wire bus system developed by Dallas Semiconductors (the DS part of the device).  Multiple 1-wire bus devices may be connected to the bus.  By default the bus uses GPIO4 on the Pi.  However you can specify which GPIO to be used by setting a value in `/boot/config.txt`.

The DHT22 uses a 1 wire protocol but it is not compatible with the Dallas 1-wire bus.  You can connect a DHT22 to any spare GPIO.  The DHT22 does not use a bus system so only one DHT22 may be attached per GPIO.  You can connect as many DHT22 as you have spare GPIO.